# execute asynctask on View Pager only page selected

Tags: android-asynctask, android-viewpager

How to make execute asynctask on View Pager only page selected / opened?
like friendcaster for android execute asynctask when page opened. Or like tabhost method only execute when page opened, but when move to other tabs and back again not reload again.
thanks before. :D

Answer (score -1):

Add that code to your pages:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);    
}
```

You can have `AsyncTask` in your first page class, for example, and call it from your `ViewPager` class.